# Прерывание выполнения программы

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var api = this.Api;
    string groupName = textBox1.Text;
    var group = api.Utils.ResolveScreenName(groupName);
    int totalCount = 0;
    int count = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    if (count == 0)
        break;
    ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall = api.Wall.Get(-group.Id.Value, out totalCount, count);
    PhotoUrl(wall);
 }
```

Но ругается на `break` таким образом:

> Error 1   No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue

Как мне заставить пользователя на `numericUpDown1` выбрать число, отличное от нуля?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (count != 0)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall = api.Wall.Get(-group.Id.Value, out totalCount, count);
    PhotoUrl(wall);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`break` служит для прерывания циклов. Чтобы выйти из функции, используйте `return`

Comment: На одну функцию - если это возможно - один ретурн, плодить их плохая практика.

Comment: Согласен. Но в данном случае это не принципиально, на мой взгляд

Comment: в данном случае нужно просто не выполнять несколько строк кода, если я правильно понимаю задачу, IF - отлично с этим справится и без ретурна, если поменять его условие на противоположное.

Comment: @Mirdin Почему один return? Если, скажем, в цикле несколько возможных варианта и мы знаем их приоритет (а очень часто так и бывает) - всегда пишу return, чтобы не плодить громоздкие if..else

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, не очень понятно о каком цикле и приоритетах вы говорите, но лишние ретурны приводят к образованию спагети-кода, не всегда согласен, но слишком часто чтоб такая практика стала антипатерном. И еще, что громоздкого в if... else - несколько лишних строк?

Comment: @Mirdin упс, вместо "цикл" должно быть "функция" =) Да я согласен, что всего нужно в меру, но я, например, до 3-4 return оставляю без колебаний. Не люблю if..else, когда начинается уже else...if (большая вложенность)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, дайте я угадаю, вам никогда не приходилось отлаживать чужой код с 3-4 разными выходами их функций? Проблема в том что любой код развивается, и тот кто отлаживает ваш "...код, без колебаний..." вполне может оказаться маньяком, знающим ваш адрес :)

Comment: @Mirdin ахаха, Вы почти правы. Спасибо, я обязательно учту этот момент (либо буду писать меньше такой лапши, либо ставить толстые двери)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Немного дополню: стараются избегать множества точек выхода из функции, так как это облегчает чтение кода. Когда есть только один вход в функцию и один выход, невозможно что-нибудь упустить. Если же есть несколько выходов, разбросанных внутри большой функции, то очень легко их не заметить и тем самым не верно понять детали работы программы. Кроме того, это замедляет скорость чтения кода.

Comment: Другая причина, как сказал Алексей - спагетти-код. Если вам требуется несколько `return`, то, вполне возможно, что нужно поменять архитектуру функции (хотя, не факт). Но в общем-то, фанатеть не нужно - в первую очередь, пользуйтесь головой. А вообще, это отдельная большая тема - написание хорошего кода.

Comment: @Dmi7ry Про написание хорошего кода: наконец-то заимел книгу М.Фаулера "Рефакторинг". Он вообще не видит катастрофы в написании изначально не очень красивого кода (если, например, срок очень жмет), но приводит кучу способов код улучшить "по-горячему".

Comment: @Mirdin, "На одну функцию - если это возможно - один ретурн, плодить их плохая практика." - не согласен. Уже давно все адекватные среды умеют ставить breakpoint на закрывающую фигурную скобку. Этот breakpoint сработает после любого return'а.